# How to edit grub.cfg file for Ubuntu installation moved to another drive?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, ssd

I am following [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MovingLinuxPartition) to move my existing Ubuntu 18.04 installation from HDD to SSD drive (I also have Windows installed on this SSD drive).

I have successfully came to the *Step 5: Update grub and fstab*. There is written:

> Using gedit, find and replace every "(hdX,Y)" appropriately

> X and Y should be replaced based on your new partition's /dev/sdZY or /dev/hdZY, if Z is 'a' then X should be '0', if Z is 'b' then X should be '1' and so on.

The device name of my new partiton is `nvme0n1p5`. What should be my X and Y?

Also, in this file, I haven't found any entries like "(hdX,Y)", I have only found entries "hd0,gpt3" (without the parenthesis). Does that matter?

> Using gedit, find and replace every "--fs-uuid --set " based on new generated UUID.

I have found also other use cases of the old UUID, not just the ones with "--fs-uuid --set" before them. Should I also change them?

[Here](https://pastebin.com/u0XZSAaq) is my grub.cfg file.

Comment: While I prefer a new install, so everything is correct, you can chroot into system and totally reinstall grub to fully update everything. If you can boot, you can update from within your install. You can violate the rule of not editing /ubuntu/grub and edit just first boot stanza with correct info. Then an update will correct then all. You may need to use efibootmgr if UEFI to have correct entries in UEFI. Full reinstall of grub will also correct that.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
hd0,5
```

Also,

```
hd0,gpt5
```

should be equivalent.

- `hd0` represents your disk, `nvme0n1`
- `5` or `gpt5` represents your fifth partition on this disk

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. What about the second part of the question - should I change all old UUID-s with the new one?

Comment: I haven't done this myself... However, reading the instructions you linked to, you should go ahead and change the UUIDs. They need to be unique for each partition on your system (regardless of which physical disk the partition is on). By the way, on AskUbuntu, it is better to ask separate questions, instead of grouping multiple queries into a single question. This is because you are likely to get better answers from different people who have expertise on a particular part of your overall problem. Good luck with your data migration!

Comment: I have asked a question about another part of that tutorial [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1334037/how-to-run-grub-install-correctly) Could you answer it if you maybe know the answer?