# How to run grub-install correctly?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, ssd

I am following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MovingLinuxPartition) tutorial to move my Ubuntu 18.04 from HDD to SSD and I came to the part:

> 2. Run grub setup for new partition

> shell> sudo grub-install -d /media/<new partition uuid>/usr/lib/grub/[instance] /dev/sda

> Where [instance] is the version you want to make bootable

My question is, what should I select as `[instance]` part? In the folder `/media/<new partition uuid>/usr/lib/grub/`, I have a link file "grub-mkconfig_lib" and a folder "i386-pc". In that "i386-pc" folder, there are many files with the extension ".mod". I don't know what the tutorial meant with *Where [instance] is the version you want to make bootable*

I am also curious if the last part of the command - `/dev/sda` is correct? Because I have the new Ubuntu partition on the disk `/dev/nvme0n1`, not  `/dev/sda` (which is the HDD).

I have Windows installed on that same SSD disk. Is it possible that this command would somehow break this, so I couldn't boot to Windows anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Yep. You’ll want that `i386-pc` instance.

```
sudo grub-install -d /media/{DEVICE_GUID}/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/ /dev/nvme0n1
```

This will install Grub on the device specified